# angularJS directive not immediately honoring ng-show/ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following section of HTML in an angularJS application. The <div/> tag for appointment-list is showing a listing of appointments. This directive is basically just a table.

```
    <div ng-show="loading">Loading...</div>
    <div ng-show="!loading && (appointments.length == 0)">No Appointments Found</div>
    <div ng-hide="loading || (appointments.length == 0)">Test123</div>
    <div ng-hide="loading || (appointments.length == 0)" appointment-list source="appointments" appointment-selected="appointmentSelected(appointment)"></div>
```

I then have the following in my controller. I am setting a loading variable while things are in-flight, and then I also filter the appointments on the page according to text in a text box.

```
    $scope.$watch('selectedDate', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal) {
            $scope.loading = true;
            Appointment.query({year: newVal.getYear()+1900, month: newVal.getMonth()+1, day: newVal.getDate()}, function(data) {
                    $scope.allAppointments = data;
                    $scope.appointments = $scope.filterAppointments();
                    $scope.loading = false;
            });
    }

    });
```

My issue is that the hiding of the div for my custom directive isn't happening properly. The table should be disappearing exactly along with the "Test123" string and its not. When I go from a selected date with the table populated to a date with nothing on there, the "Test123" will be replace with the loading (therefor its being hidden, and loading being shown) but the table remains until after the loading process is complete at which point the table will disappear

Can someone explain why the delay? Why is the directive not responding exactly like the div above it?

**Edit**

Here is a plnkr which shows the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/khxQuaM6sxTx5RszvowX?p=preview

Basically click on the buttons at the top to load the two datasets. I have a timeout in there to simulate some of the think time on the server. Whenever you see "Loading..." the div for the appointmentList table should not be shown since ng-hide will evaluate to true because loading is true, yet is doesn't disappear.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've added a plnkr example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `$parent` to access the model `loading` since the directive `appointmentList` creates an isolated scope. Make the following change to the *last div containing the table* and you will achieve the effect you want.

```
<div ng-hide="$parent.loading || (appointments.length == 0)" appointment-list source="appointments" ... ></div>
```

You don't need to use `$parent` to refer to `appointments`, since you pass this model to the directive. But there is no harm to add `$parent` like `$parent.appointments.length == 0`, since you have `appointments` defined anyway in the parent scope.

Btw, you should also set `appointments` to be `empty` in the watcher like this

```
if (newVal) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.appointments = [];  //add this
```

to make the condition `appointments.length == 0` useful.

Comment: So, within an element for any directive, all the ng-* directive attributes on that element will refer to the scope created within the directive? Would another approach be to pass in a variable like I did with source to hide/show this? What is the best practice approach on this?

Comment: @jr. If you specify `scope` in the directive, then it will created an isolated `scope`. To prove it, remove `      scope: {
        source: '=',
        appointmentSelected: '&'
      },` then it should does what you want. Since no isolated scope will be created. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, I get it now. So, anything in the element which is the directive will be referencing that new scope. So, to clarify.. I either need to create scope and pass in those variable (like I do for source), or reference the $parent scope in the element attributes, or don't create a scope at all in the directive and it will just have access to whatever scope the directive is placed in.

Comment: Just one more clarification, since I am passing in "source" to the directive shouldn't I be doing "source.length == 0"? Finally,do I really need to be doing a watch internally in the directive on source and then assigning that to $scope.appointments? I realize that ultimately the appointments within the directive scope will be set to the value of source, but seems kind of redundant. I was basically just copying from some examples on the web.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I've got a custom directive with an isolate scope. I've got ng-show="$parent.show" on the outside html (to be replaced by my directive's template, but it still fails to hide when show is false. In fact, even ng-show="false" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is `$scope.appointments` being set within the same tick as `$scope.loading`?

If `$scope.filterAppointments` is doing something asynchronous, you want to make sure `$scope.loading` is set to false at the end of that process.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, angular didn't want to show/hide when applied to an ul > li element, in IE or Chrome. Changing it to a div works perfectly. I am on angular 1.2.14. Not sure if this is a bug or not, but it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used ng-cloak, it keeps the browser from displaying the template while my application is loading.

Take a look at this:
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jun/02/AngularJs-ngcloak-Problems-on-large-Pages